# How to create separate sub-plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

These are the outputs I am getting for my PDP:

[output 1][1]

How can I modify the code to create a separate PDP for each feature  (6 separate plots, not combined in 1 plot)?

## Code Source

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604209/creating-a-partial-dependant-plot-for-a-prediction-function/604288?noredirect=1#comment1121216_604288

## Code:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
from sklearn.utils import check_X_y, check_array
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



data_set = pd.read_excel("Alpha copy.xlsx")
pd.set_option('max_columns', 35)
pd.set_option('max_rows', 300)
data_set.head(300)

X, y = data_set[["B","D","k","fc","Le","N"]], data_set [["R"]]



class DummyRegressor(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y):
        # Check that X and y have correct shape
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y, y_numeric=True)
        self.X_ = X
        self.y_ = y
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        X = check_array(X)

            # X is an numpy array, not a pandas DataFrame.
            # Make sure the columns of X are in the order required by `objective`
            return objective(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], X[:, 3], X[:, 4], X[:, 5])

dummy_reg = DummyRegressor()
dummy_reg.fit(X, y.values.ravel())    

display = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(
    dummy_reg, X, [0, 1,2,3,4,5],
    feature_names=["B", "D","k", "fc","Le", "N"]
)


 display.axes_[0][0].set_ylabel("R")
```

Comment: It looks like PartialDependenceDisplay does not accept a figure as an argument.  If it did, you could pass it a subfigure, and it should work.  As it is, you will have to make a feature request to sklearn, and in the meantime combine your plots in other graphics software

Comment: Actually, I take that back - it seems there is some support: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_partial_dependence_visualization_api.html#plotting-partial-dependence-for-two-features

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.subplots`. Here are a couple of example vectors being plotted on a 2x2 set of graphics.

```
# Vectors to plot
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
c = [1,3,3,5,5,6]
d = [0,2,2,5,5,6]
```

First setup the plt subplot figure with number of rows and cols you want.

```
# Setup figure
plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(15,6))
```

The subplots start at index 1, so here it will be plt.subplot(total num rows, total num cols, index of the graphic).

```
# Plot 1 (rows, cols, position 0)
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(a, b, c='red')
plt.title('graphic 1')

# Plot 2 (rows, cols, position 1)
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(c, d, c='gold')
plt.title('graphic 2')

# Plot 3 (rows, cols, position 1)
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(c, d, c='green')
plt.title('graphic 3')

# Plot 4 (rows, cols, position 1)
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(c, d, c='black')
plt.title('graphic 4');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the problem is how to apply that to my code. I am using `PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm... Not sure. Maybe you can try to extract the plots from your output, assign to different variables then to plot separately.